# FileBeat doesn't see to be doing anything

Tags: logging, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat, telemetry

I have FileBeat installed as a service and I've set the following config:

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    -
      paths:
        - C:\LogFiles\log.log

      input_type: filebeat

  registry_file: "C:/ProgramData/filebeat/registry"

output:

  logstash:
    hosts: ["XX.XX.XX.XX:5044"]

shipper:

logging:

  files:
    path: C:\fileBeatLogs
    rotateeverybytes: 10485760 # = 10MB
  level: error
```

I've also tried the paths with forward slashes

The registry file is being changed when I start the service, but not at any other times and there are no logs being written to `C:\fileBeatLogs\.`

Comment: you should see if switching your log level to info gives you any clues, I've found info level logging really useful for debugging filebeat

Comment: @WillBarnwell isn't debug more than info anyway?

Comment: Yes, and both are more than error, which is what youre set to now. If you aren't seeing any logs, you could try explicitly setting options like `to_files: true`

Comment: That's given some logs now, loads actually!

Comment: If you still seem to be running into trouble, see if you can find some logs about it and add them to your question